# In how many ways 5 different rings can be worn on 4 fingers?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Is the answer $4^5$ or $4 \times 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8$?

The rationale behind $4 \times 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8$ is that first ring has four options, the second ring has $5$ options, since the second ring can come underneath the first, and so on.

I think $4^5$ is correct since $4 \times 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8$ is over counting the number of possibilities.

Comment: Why does the second ring have 5 options? (Bonus question: are the ring wearing fingers, or are the fingers wearing rings?)

Comment: @Gae.S. I understand Ayush's thinking here. The "second" ring is not necessarily the second ring you put on, but, having put the rings on, the second you consider. The first ring can go on any of $4$ fingers. The second can go on any of $4$ fingers, but also has the option of being "under" (that is, between the 1st ring and the knuckle). And the placement of the 3rd ring is also then dependent upon its relative placement concerning the first 2. OP's thinking is along the right lines, and 4x5x6x7x8 is more likely to be true than $4^5$ which takes no account of relative placement of

Comment: @Gae.S. (cont'd) relative placements of the rings on the actual fingers themselves. (And of course one finger must have at least 2 rings on, by the pigeonhole principle. But it's tricky proving that it *is* actually 4x5x6x7x8, and I'm going to have to go away and think about it.

Comment: This may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379068/number-of-ways-of-arranging-5-distinct-rings-on-5-fingers?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

Five identical rings can be placed on four fingers (using [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))) in $\binom{5+4-1}{4-1}=\binom{8}{3}$ ways.

Because the rings are **not** identical, they can then be permuted, in $5!$ ways.

So the answer is:

$$\binom{8}{3}5!=\frac{8!}{3!}=4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8$$.

Which happens to be $P(8,5)$, interpreted as:

> Pick 5 letters from ABCDEFGH. The remainder are the bars, the selection is mapped alphabetically to 12345 for the rings.

Comment: I am not sure about multiplying by $5!$ , we generally do it for boxes

Comment: @Bulbasaur  Imagine placing the rings on the four fingers from bottom left to top right.  The order in which the rings appear on the fingers matters.

Comment: The reason it’s P(8,5) is just like “stars and bars” — with 5 stars for the rings, 3 bars to split up the 4 fingers — but with the stars labelled A–E, rather than identical as in classic “stars and bars”.  The possible arrangements are exactly the ways of placing the 5 labelled stars among the 8 slots, i.e. P(8,5).  For example, “ring B on finger 1, rings EA on finger 2, rings DC on finger 4” corresponds to the arrangement `B|EA||DC`.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine; P(8,5) means the number of ways to pick 5 objects from a list of 8, where the order is important. You might pick a bar. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n)

Comment: @JMP: I’m well aware what $P(8,5)$ means.  I’m saying: from the 8 positions, pick 5 (with order) and mark these as A,B,C,D,E, and then mark the 3 remaining positions as bars.  (Standard stars-and-bars has essentially two proofs — “pick the 3 bars, consider the rest as stars” or “pick the 5 stars, consider the rest as bars”.  I’m saying: adapt the second of these proofs, to use labelled stars instead of indistinguishable, so you get $P(5,8)$ instead of $C(5,8)$.)

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine; oh right, you place the 5 stars  *into* 8 slots. True.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, each finger needn't have a ring, and in this context, $4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8$ is indeed correct.

An easy to understand way from the diagrams below where $F$ represents *finger*, $R$ *ring* and taking that a ring is attached to a finger to its right, initially we have

$-F-F-F-F$ and the first ring has $4$ places to get inserted

On inserting a ring in one of the gaps, we have. say,  $-F-F-R-F-F$
which clearly shows that there are now $5$ gaps for the next ring

Also try placing the next ring beside a placed ring, $-F-F-R-R-F-F$
and see that there are now $6$ gaps for the next ring

Each time you place a ring anywhere, an additional gap gets created,
thus the answer is $4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8$

Answer (score 1):

You solution is very clever. I believe $4 \times 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8$ is indeed correct. The logic is sound.

To answer your question, there is no double counting. If there were double counting, there would be two paths that yielded the same outcome. But if each ring is sequentially placed in the correct relative order as your original method suggests, any alternate path would create two rings in an incorrect relative order. And adding more rings won't change that incorrect relative order.

Answer (score 1):

$4^5$ is the correct answer, but to an altered version of the problem, namely this:

> Given a predetermined sequence of five rings which must be put on in that order, how many ways are there of wearing them on four fingers?

In this problem, we have exactly one way of choosing each successive ring: we take the next item from the predetermined sequence.

Yet some configurations are not possible under this constraint. For instance, if we're required to put on the rings in ABCDE order, it means that we can never produce a configuration in which the E ring is covered by another ring which was put on after it. Since E is put on last, it is the outermost ring of whichever finger it goes to.

The original problem has no such constraint: the rings are chosen in any order. So, when we put on the first ring, we not only have a choice of four fingers, but of five rings. Then a choice from among four rings, three, two and one.

But not all the choices of rings produce unique configurations. Given different ring-wearing sequences like ABCDE and BACDE, we can still easily produce an identical configuration. Under both these orders we can, for instance, put A on the index finger, B on the middle finger, and CDE on the pinky. Permutation of the rings provides *some* extra configurations, but not in a trivial way.

It's actually fairly surprising that the result is nothing but a tidy rising product from 4 to 8.